# Multiple condition checks in the query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the below query where I pass in 4 parameters from the UI.  BU and Region have radio button options of (All, Option1, Option2, Option3 etc) in the UI. Options 1 - 3 are values in the data whereas 'All' is not.

Is there a way to write the below more efficiently?  For example, if BU or Region values are 'All' "from the UI", (which are not values in the dataset), is there a character I can assign to bu or region if all is selected so that the query knows to select all the values?

I don't know if there is such a thing but I want to avoid having to do something like the below.

```
     public string GetAvgSeatPrice(string bu, string region, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {

        if (bu.Equals("All"))
        {
            var averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                                    where
                                         //r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu) &&
                                         r.Region.Equals(region) &&
                                         r.StartDate >= startDate &&
                                         r.EndDate <= endDate &&
                                         r.ActualPrice > 0
                                    select r.ActualPrice).Average();

            var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

            return AvgSeatPrice;
        }
        else if (region.Equals("All"))
        {
            var averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                                    where
                                         r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu) &&
                                        // r.Region.Equals(region) &&
                                         r.StartDate >= startDate &&
                                         r.EndDate <= endDate &&
                                         r.ActualPrice > 0
                                    select r.ActualPrice).Average();

            var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

            return AvgSeatPrice;
        }
        else if (bu.Equals("All") && region.Equals("All"))
        {
            var averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                                    where
                                         //r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu) &&
                                         // r.Region.Equals(region) &&
                                         r.StartDate >= startDate &&
                                         r.EndDate <= endDate &&
                                         r.ActualPrice > 0
                                    select r.ActualPrice).Average();

            var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

            return AvgSeatPrice;
        }
        else
        {
            var averageSeatPrice = (from r in db.Registrations
                                    where
                                         r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu) &&
                                         r.Region.Equals(region) &&
                                         r.StartDate >= startDate &&
                                         r.EndDate <= endDate &&
                                         r.ActualPrice > 0
                                    select r.ActualPrice).Average();

            var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

            return AvgSeatPrice;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Do you have error?

Comment: If I pass in Option 1, 2 or 3, it works because those are values in the data that I can assign to those options.  If I select 'All', there's nothing for it to compare against because there's no value to assign to All to compare in the Where.   I'm wondering if there's a character I can assign to the All option so that it doesn't filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
public string GetAvgSeatPrice(string bu, string region, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
    {
        var averageSeatPrice = (
            from r in db.Registrations
            where (bu == "ALL" || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu))
            && (region == "ALL" || r.Region.Equals(region))
            && r.StartDate >= startDate
            && r.EndDate <= endDate
            && r.ActualPrice > 0
            select r.ActualPrice).Average();

        var AvgSeatPrice = "$" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", averageSeatPrice);

        return AvgSeatPrice;
    }
```

Because of the OR (||), if the selection is "ALL" the second condition is never checked and do not narrow the selection down by the given property. It is checked only if the selection is NOT "ALL" and in such case the selection is narrowed down.

Comment: Thank you, however, 'ALL' is not a value in the dataset, I'm looking for a character to replace 'ALL' with so that I can assign it to bu before the query so that the query does not filter.  I don't even know if there is such a thing but I'm trying to find a better solution to the above code which I updated to attempt to clarify my desire.

Comment: I looked at your updated question and I still think that my answer does just what you want. Notice, that I do NOT compare "ALL" to the dataset in the first part (before the ||). I simply check what comes from the UI and if it is "ALL" then the whole condition is already true and the second part is never checked, which means you will get all records.

Comment: Lets say that the only values in the BU field are 'Cats', 'Dogs' and 'Birds'.  If 'ALL' is passed in from the UI, based on your solution, it will restrict the records to 0 because 'ALL' is not a value in BU.  Right?  What am I missing?

Comment: @JReam.  The assumption here is that "bu" is from the UI and "r.BusinessUnit" is from the database.  Thus, comparing to "bu" means comparing to the UI.  The OR condition "short circuits" the other comparison because it will equal true.

Comment: If I wrote this (r.BusinessUnit.Equals("ALL") || r.BusinessUnit.Equals(bu)) then you would be right. But this is not my solution. Inside the parentheses is just a condition (composed of two smaller conditions) that returns either true or false. It is checked against all records in your database and the records for which it returns true are returned. Notice, that if you pass "ALL" the first part that is bu=="ALL" is already true. And it is true for every record so every record will be returned. Just try it.

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you and thanks for explaining.  Someday I'll hope to understand all of this and to be able to contribute back to green horns like myself.... only have about 6 months into MVC/EF now but loving it.  Just wish I had a senior dev to rely on for these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this isn't exactly what you're asking to not have provided (I could interpret multiple if/else case/etc two separate ways from your question).  But you could do something like this:

```
var averageSeatPrice = 
    from r in db.Registrations
    where r.StartDate >= startDate &&
          r.EndDate <= endDate &&
          r.ActualPrice > 0

// note I'm assuming your "bu" "all" option is represented as the string "All"
if (bu.ToUpper() != "ALL") 
    averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice
        .Where(w => w.BusinessUnit == bu);

if (region.ToUpper() !+ "ALL")
    averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice
        .Where(w => w.Region == region);

averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice select r.ActualPrice).Average();
```

Sorry I'm less clear with the linq syntax you're using (or I would have done my answer with that), hopefully this helps though.

Basically the if statement states if the option is ***not*** all, then tack on that portion of the where clause otherwise it's not tacked on, and never becomes a part of the query.

> Kritner - can you elaborate a bit on what you're doing here? seems like an interesting approach too

Given `BusinessUnit` can have the following values:

```
option1
option2
option3
```

if `bu` is provided as `option1` then we need our where clause to contain `where BusinessUnit = 'option1'`

so:

```
if (bu.ToUpper() != "ALL")  // bu is option1, evaluates true
    averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice // add the where clause to the IQueryable
        .Where(w => w.BusinessUnit == bu); // deferred execution, so have not yet executed query, and can continue to modify and only do a single trip to db
```

Now on the other hand, if `bu` is "ALL" or string.empty, or whatever you want it to be that isn't a valid value, then we don't want BusinessUnit to be a part of the where clause at all... the posted code accomplishes this scenario as well:

```
if (bu.ToUpper() != "ALL") // this evaluates to false (bu is "ALL"), don't add the where clause information at all.
    averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice
        .Where(w => w.BusinessUnit == bu);
```

Each `averageSeatPrice = averageSeatPrice.Where(...)` is simply tacked on to the query until a point at which you enumerate the results.

Comment: Kritner - can you elaborate a bit on what you're doing here?  seems like an interesting approach too.